# How to marshal a const char* parameter in function pointer used to send data from C++ dll to C# to avoid Release build crash

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

I register a function pointer that takes a string as parameter in the C++ dll that is used to send text back to the C# application. I tried to marshal the string parameter as IntPtr and BStr in addition to others. With the debug build I have no crash. With the release build the data are returned correctly (tested with log to a txt file). However, the C# program crashes with AccessViolationException.

Here is the code:

A: using BStr

C++:

```
typedef void(*callbackFunction)(BSTR resultDataJson);
 extern "C" DLLEXPORT int setReceiveFunction(callbackFunction funcPointer)
{       
    //function pointer is stored
    return 0;
}
//send the data back with function pointer
void MyClass::sendCallback(const QByteArray& msg)
{   
    if (this->m_callbackFunctionForReceivedData != nullptr)
    {
        BSTR resultMsg = this->ANSItoBSTR(msg.data());
        this->m_callbackFunctionForReceivedData(resultMsg);
    }   
}
```

C#:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
 public delegate void receiveCallbackData([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string resultDataJson);

    [DllImport("./myDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

    static public extern int setReceiveFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] receiveCallbackData functionCallback);
//callback function where data are received
private void functionCallback(string receivedJsonData)
{
    //The received string can be logged here and looks correct.
}
```

B. using IntPtr

```
typedef void (*callbackFunction)(const char* resultDataJson);
 extern "C" DLLEXPORT int setReceiveFunction(callbackFunction funcPointer)
{       
    //function pointer is stored
    return 0;
}
//send the data back with function pointer
void MyClass::sendCallback(const QByteArray& msg)
{   
    if (this->m_callbackFunctionForReceivedData != nullptr)
    {
       this->m_callbackFunctionForReceivedData(msg.data());
    }   
}
```

C#:

```
 [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void receiveCallbackData(IntPtr resultDataJson);

    [DllImport("./MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

    static public extern int setReceiveFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] receiveCallbackData functionCallback);

 private void functionCallback(IntPtr receivedJsonDataInt)
 {
        string receivedJsonData = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(receivedJsonDataInt);
         //The received string can be logged here and looks correct.
 }
```

Both work in Debug but crash in Release. Why? What is the solution to this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add the exception info.

Comment: The [UnmanagedFuinctionPointer] is not correct, the function pointer declaration in the C++ code does not specify __stdcall.  So it is Cdecl.  The MSVC++ compiler has a diagnostic for this in the Debug configuration, unclear why it doesn't fire.  The other possible flaw is that it is not obvious that the C# code handles the delegate object for the setReceiveFunction() correctly.  It must be protected against garbage collection, best done by storing it in a *static* field.

Comment: Thank you very much again for pointing me to the error. It was indeed the CallingConvention. StdCall however did not work. I changed the following:[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]. It must be Cdecl.